# Can I use COUNTIF on multiple arrays?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use SUM with COUNTIF to decipher how many dates in one array, appear in another array.

Let `M2` and `M4` be a start and end date, as well as `H7` and `G7`.

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(T15#,U15#))
```

works, where `T15#` and `U15#` are sequence arrays.

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(T15#,SEQUENCE(M4-M2+1,1,M2,1)))
```

works, replacing `U15#` with the sequence array.

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(SEQUENCE(H7-G7+1,1,G7,1),SEQUENCE(M4-M2+1,1,M2,1)))
```

doesn't work.

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(SEQUENCE(H7-G7+1,1,G7,1),U15#))
```

also doesn't work.

I can't decipher the issue as `T15#` works, which is the same as the sequence.

If this isn't possible, is there a possible solution?

Comment: It is easier to help you if you provide some sample data and your expected output - best by using markdown table.

Comment: `T15#` works because `COUNTIF()` finds it as a `range object` while when using `SEQUENCE()` function as `Criteria_Range` it finds it as `array object` hence why it is not working. As already you are aware that `COUNTIF()` or `COUNTIFS()` or any `IFs` family functions don't work with arrays in criteria range

Comment: Is there a potential workaround for this?

Comment: One way: `=LET(x, SEQUENCE(15,,--"1/1/24"), SUM(MMULT(N(SEQUENCE(M3+1-M2,,M2)=TOROW(x)),x^0)))` or using `BYROW()` also try to search such questions here in `SO` these type of questions has been asked a lot and there are solutions as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like you may have asked about an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Let me explain:

---

**X**:

You need to find the count of days in overlapping date-ranges, right? In the body of your post you are working towards two starting and two ending days in 4 seperate cells to try and create these date-ranges.

---

**Y**:

Since you think you need arrays to solve X you ended up with the problem where `COUNTIF()` is not accepting your two arrays in it's parameters. This is what I'd call problem Y.

To answer problem Y regarding `COUNTIF()`; this function requires a range reference in it's 1st parameter. So to overcome this, you could compare a vertical vs. an horizontal array. In short:

```
=SUM(N(<Array1>=TOROW(<Array2>)))
```

Here `<Array1>` and `<Array2>` are placeholders. You need to swap these pieces out for your actual *vertical* arrays.

This works because, taking into consideration that `COUNTIF()` was a working option for you when you where refering to actual ranges, one value in `<Array1>` can't equal more than one value in `<Array2>` (they are ranges of dates).

Since you are using `SEQUENCE()` to build your arrays, try to built your `<Array2>` in this horizontal matter directly. That way you can leave `TOROW()` out. Something along these lines:

```
=SUM(N(SEQUENCE(H9-H7,,H7)=SEQUENCE(,M4-M2,M2)))
```

---

**Suggestion**:

Try to solve X with simple math instead using your 4 cells:

```
=MIN(M4,H9)-MAX(M2,H7)+1
```

Comment: This MIN and MAX works perfect, definitely seems an XY-problem so bravo!

Answer (score 2):

With this formula:

`=BYROW(B1:B4,LAMBDA(inp,SUM(IF(A1:A8=inp,1,0))))`

the result is the count of occurence of specific value

[image]

if you need the total of occurences then with SUM

`=SUM(BYROW(B1:B4,LAMBDA(inp,SUM(IF(A1:A8=inp,1,0)))))`

Comment: This works so thank you! I think as mentioned by another user however, I was overcomplicating with an XY-problem and their answer has simplified this right down. Thanks again for a valid solution!

Answer (score 1):

As commented above by me:

> *`T15#` works because `COUNTIF()` finds it as a **range object** while when*
> *using `SEQUENCE()` function as **criteria_range** it finds it as **array***
> ***object** hence why it is not working. As already you are aware that*
> *`COUNTIF()` or `COUNTIFS()` or any `IFs` family functions don't work with*
> ***arrays** in **criteria range***

---

There could be many ways of resolving this perhaps I will use `MMULT()` or `BYROW()` as mentioned in comments above, which is a potential work around for the same, when using the arrays within the functions, if it has to be without using it as an **array object** then i wont be using these functions and will be opting out as mentioned by OP using `COUNTIF()` or `COUNTIFS()` thus wont make things complicated unless its required:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>M6</kbd>

```
=LET(x, SEQUENCE(15,,--"1/1/24"), SUM(MMULT(N(SEQUENCE(M4+1-M2,,M2)=TOROW(x)),x^0)))
```

---

Or,

```
=SUM(--BYROW(SEQUENCE(M4-M2+1,,M2),LAMBDA(x, OR(--(x=SEQUENCE(15,,--"1/1/24"))))))
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it is a great insight! I haven’t encountered the difference for Array Objects and Range Objects before.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to do something like (where `A` and `B` are separate arrays):

```
=CountIf(x, A <union> B)
```

Why don't you simply do this:

```
=CountIf(x, A) + CountIf(x, B)
```

(As both arrays don't intersect, this should be correct, isn't it?)

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is asking. There are two starting arrays. Let's call them `A` and `B`. When OP is using an actual range reference for these two arrays (thus written out in cells), the `COUNTIF()` works, but stops working when OP is trying to reach his goal of creating the two arrays directly through `SEQUENCE()`. Speaking with terms you have been using here, there is no `x`.

Comment: I effectively wanted to a sum of how many times the values in Array1 appeared in Array2. 

As other users have mentioned, COUNTIF works with ranges, but not arrays and in fact I was creating an XY-problem as both arrays were indeed sequences of date ranges.